# PHP on NGINX not loading php.ini

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, nginx

I've spent a few hours today setting up WNMP (Windows, NGINX, MySQL, PHP) on Windows 8.1. Everything's working perfectly until I try to access my Wordpress installation:

```
Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.
```

Well, I've got `php_mysql.dll` and `php_mysqli.dll` enabled in `php.ini` - which isn't being loaded. php_info() gives me

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   C:\WINDOWS
Loaded Configuration File           (none)
```

I've tried everything I can think of (`PHPRC` environment variable and copying `php.ini` into `C:\Windows`) but PHP won't play ball. I'm using NGINX 1.7.0, PHP 5.5.12 (thread-safe) and MySQL Server 5.6.17. I have restarted the server (in its entirety - NGINX, PHP FastCGI and MySQL) about three hundred times.

Comment: Try following the steps here: http://www.mrxuri.com/2013/06/08/wnmp.html

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network because its not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](https://www.superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 0):

1st. check php startup error. U find there. php unable to load modules.

check php error log.

2nd. check php.ini file and check **extension** directory defined?

and its correctly pointed?

maybe php unable to find to find **ext directory**.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems time ago with php.ini and NGINX to.

Finally, I found a solution. Create a file with this name: .user.ini in the root of your domain. In this file you can add any php.ini sentence and works perfectly.